# Changing the colour of UIView that is created dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, tags

I am creating a `UIView` and its subviews (such as UITextfield, UIButton etc.) dynamically( by reading from JSON )

I am giving tags to all `UIView` and try to call by tag.

For instance I am trying to change the background colour of a view inside another view.

parent view's tag is 1, subview's is 11.

My sample code is as follows;

```
UIView *temp = [self.view viewWithTag:1];

if([[temp viewWithTag:11] isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
{
    [((UIView*)[temp viewWithTag:11]) setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

But there is no change, no effect.

Could you please help me on solving this.

Comment: Does it go inside if block ?

Comment: its working fine your code is ok so please check once again that you have assign tags correctly to your view

Comment: beside your problem, instead of assign numbers to your view use `Enum` or constants.

Comment: NeverHopeless yes it goes inside if block,
JaswantSinghRajpurohit the point is dynamic creation may be problem of not changing the view

Comment: @erdemgc it doesn't matter whether is created dynamically or not. At the end of the process both ways return a pointer to a UI object. The issue is something else, such as tags not set correctly etc

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin i think the same way, since i am logging the uiview and its properties looks correct

Answer (score 0):

```
#define PARENT_VIEW_TAG 1
#define CHILD_VIEW_TAG 11

    UIView *parentView = [self.view viewWithTag:PARENT_VIEW_TAG];

    for (UIView *vw in [parentView subviews]) {

        if(vw.tag == CHILD_VIEW_TAG)
        {
            [vw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
    }
```